Oracle SQL select rows between two rows that have a set value with groups
I have a table like below:
enter image description here
For each group, I would like to select the rows between stop 20231 and 21567. So the result table should look like this:
enter image description here
How do I write my SQL query to achieve this in Oracle?
I have tried this:
SELECT Groups, Sort_Sequence, Stop_number
FROM table 
WHERE 
Sort_Sequence >= (select Sort_Sequence from table where Stop_number = 20231)
and Sort_Sequence <= (select Sort_Sequence from table where stop_number = 21567)

I have got this error:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


As the error message says, one of the subqueries (or both) is returning more than one record. In other words, you actually have more than one record with the same Stop_number. That seems to be normal, according to your example data.
You should include the "group" in the subquery. Maybe using a correlated query:
SELECT Groups, Sort_Sequence, Stop_number
  FROM table t
  WHERE Sort_Sequence >= (select Sort_Sequence from table where Stop_number = 20231 and Groups = t.Groups)
    AND Sort_Sequence <= (select Sort_Sequence from table where Stop_number = 21567 and Groups = t.Groups)

Having said that, your code will fail again if there are inconsistencies in your data (for instance, if there is more than one record with the same Stop_number inside the same Group). I'll advise you to rewrite it in a different way (probably using a join and not subqueries), but that depends on your exact needs.

You can use analytic functions with conditional aggregation to find the start- and end-stop-numbers and then filter the rows against those bounds using an inline view. This will only read the table once (compared to using correlated sub-queries which will read the table once for the base query and then once for each correlated sub-query, so would be less efficient):
SELECT Groups,
       Sort_Sequence,
       Stop_number
FROM   (
  SELECT Groups,
         Sort_Sequence,
         Stop_number,
         MIN(CASE stop_number WHEN 20231 THEN sort_sequence END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY groups) AS start_sequence,
         MAX(CASE stop_number WHEN 21567 THEN sort_sequence END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY groups) AS end_sequence
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  sort_sequence BETWEEN start_sequence AND end_sequence
ORDER BY
       groups,
       sort_sequence

You could also use a running count of the number of starts minus the number of ends and return the rows where the total is positive (or where the row is an end):
SELECT Groups,
       Sort_Sequence,
       Stop_number
FROM   (
  SELECT Groups,
         Sort_Sequence,
         Stop_number,
         SUM(CASE stop_number WHEN 20231 THEN 1 WHEN 21567 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY groups ORDER BY sort_sequence) AS num_start_stop
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_start_stop > 0
OR     (num_start_stop = 0 AND stop_number = 21567)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Groups, Sort_Sequence, Stop_number) AS
SELECT 'A', 1, 20000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 20231 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 20001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4, 21567 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 5, 20002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 20000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, 20001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 3, 20231 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 4, 20002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 5, 20003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 6, 20004 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 7, 21567 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 8, 20005 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 9, 20006 FROM DUAL;

Both output:



GROUPS
SORT_SEQUENCE
STOP_NUMBER




A
2
20231


A
3
20001


A
4
21567


B
3
20231


B
4
20002


B
5
20003


B
6
20004


B
7
21567



fiddle

About your statement "correlated sub-queries which will read the table once for the base query and then once for each correlated sub-query", that depends on several factors (available indexes, optimizer setup, etc). If there's and index on both columns (Stop_number and Groups) (for integrity, it should be and it should be unique), the main query will read the whole table once, and each subquery will be solved using two reads (for each record of the table). One read for getting the ROWID from the index, and another read for getting the Sort_Sequence from the table, using that ROWID.

Adding the Sort_Sequence to the index will avoid the second read (per each record in the "main" query). Anyway, the optimizer will probably rewrite the code, converting it into an equivalent and much performant version. Said that, I agree with you about the general convenience of analytic functions, as the best choice for these situations. But your proposal may be too complicated for @ritarita (who, I think, was just trying to understand the error message).

You can try the below
 SELECT Groups, Sort_Sequence, Stop_number FROM table t1 
 WHERE Sort_Sequence >= (select min(Sort_Sequence) 
 from table t2
 where Stop_number = 20231 and t2.groups=t1.groups) 
 and Sort_Sequence <= (select max(Sort_Sequence) 
 from table t2 where stop_number = 21567 
 and t2.groups=t1.groups)

